# Wikipedia API ignore Cite Error or Footnotes

Tags: php, preg-replace, wikipedia-api

I am making this request:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&titles=self-administration&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvparse=&rvsection=0
```

**My goal is to get the plain-text from the intro of an article.**

It gives me back some HTML in a XML file. After `strip_tags` and `preg_replace,` to remove references, I get this:

> Self-administration is, in its medical sense, the process of a subject
>   administering a pharmacological substance to him-, her-, or itself.
>   [...] Cite error: There are  tags on this page, but the
>   references will not show without a {{Reflist}} template or a
>    tag; see the help page.

I want to remove

> Cite error: There are  tags on this page, but the
>   references will not show without a {{Reflist}} template or a
>    tag; see the help page.

How can I get ride of that either with php (`preg_replace`?) or in my initial query (ignoring errors?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$bad = ' <br /><strong class="error">Cite error: There are <code>&lt;ref&gt;</code> tags on this page, but the references will not show without a <code>&#123;&#123;Reflist&#125;&#125;</code> template or a <code>&lt;references /&gt;</code> tag; see the <a href="/wiki/Help:Cite_errors/Cite_error_refs_without_references" title="Help:Cite errors/Cite error refs without references">help page</a>.</strong> ';

$good = str_replace($bad, '', $intro);
```